# Why does the pilot light on my gas fireplace go off over night?

Tags: gas, fireplace

Pilot light on gas fireplace works fine all day. After turning thermostat down over night,it is off in the morning. We tried it three days now. Why is that happening?

Comment: A new or old fireplace?  Any changes to the gas line or thermostat?

Comment: The usual reason is that the flame sensor is defective and the unit thinks that the pilot is not lit when it's supposed to be and it shuts it off.  Did you check it?

Comment: Has it been windy at night? Verify the thermocouple is in the pilot flame. Sometimes soot builds up and moves the flame enough to have this problem.

Comment: Thank you all. After three nights of shutting off it was working last night. We will have things checked out, though!